# CanCan::Error - The can? and cannot? call cannot be used with a raw sql 'can' definition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

ability.rb

```
can :destroy, Business, Business.where(id: user.auth_ids)
```

index.html.erb

```
<% if can? :destroy, @business %>
  <%= link_to 'delete', business_path(@business.id), method: :delete%>
<% end %>
```

I want to access delete button if user field auth_ids: [] contains business id.
 
But I got error like this

```
CanCan::Error - The can? and cannot? call cannot be used with a raw sql 'can' definition.
```

Anybody could tell me what causes the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen when the syntax isn't quite right. Try a [hash with your condition](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/defining-abilities#hash-of-conditions):

```
# ability.rb

can :destroy, Business, id: user.auth_ids
```

or a [block condition with your scope](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks#block-conditions-with-scopes):

```
# ability.rb

can :destroy, Business, Business.where(id: user.auth_ids) do
  #... additional logic
end
```